# angular 5 this.data is always coming has ‘undefined’

Tags: .net, angular, angular-material

I am new to angular , I learned myself and implemented following code , but this.data is always shows as ‘undefined’ inside UploadFile function.

`this.data is always coming has ‘undefined’` inside UploadFile function – Please let me know what mistake I am doing.

Functionality of my code :-  It simple angular page where I upload the .csv file with 5 headers and some data in these columns in the file. After I click on upload same .csv file should be saved to server.

Below is my code, here I am passing filename and file content (in json format) to my .net webAPI, my webapi will save the file to server.

```
import { Component, ElementRef, Input, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Response } from '@angular/http';
import { LoggerService } from '../../core/logger.service'
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import * as Util from '../../shared/Utility';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { DataService } from '../../services/data.service';
import * as XLSX from 'xlsx';

@Component({
  templateUrl: './system.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./system.component.css']
})

export class SystemComponent {
  constructor(private router: Router, private http: HttpClient, private dataService: DataService) { }

  /*fileName = '';*/
  fileSelected = false;
  invalidFileType = false;
  file: File = null; // Variable to store file
  data: any;
  jsonData: any;
  displayError: boolean;
  errorText: string;
  responseData: any;

  @ViewChild('fileUpload') fileUpload: ElementRef;

  Reset(form) {
    console.log("Reset is clicked");
    this.fileSelected = false;
    this.file = null;
    this.invalidFileType = false;
    this.data = null;
    this.jsonData = null;
    this.responseData = null;
    this.displayError = false;
    this.errorText = null;
    this.fileUpload.nativeElement.value = "";
    console.log("Reset completed");
  }

  UploadFile(filevalue) {

    console.log("UploadFile");

    const reqbody = {
      filename: this.file.name,
      lines: JSON.stringify(this.data)
    };

    var route = "FileSave";
    this.dataService.post(reqbody, route).subscribe(
      (data: any[]) => {
        console.log("Response data: " + data);
        LoggerService.success(`File successfully uploaded to server`, true, false);
        this.responseData = data;
      },
      (error: Response) => {
        this.displayError = true;
        this.errorText = `Error saving API service ${error.status}`;
      });
  }

  onFileChange(event: any): void {
    this.file = event.target.files[0];

    if (this.file) {
      console.log("this.file.type: " + this.file.type);

      const fileName = this.file.name;
      const fileExtension = fileName.split('.').pop().toLowerCase();

      // Define allowed file extensions
      const allowedExtensions = ['xlsx', 'csv'];

      if (allowedExtensions.indexOf(fileExtension) === -1) {
        LoggerService.error(`Invalid file type. Allowed: .xlsx,.csv`, true, true);
        this.fileSelected = false;
        this.file = null;
        this.invalidFileType = true;
        this.data = null;
        this.jsonData = null;
        this.responseData = null;
        this.displayError = false;
        this.errorText = null;
        this.fileUpload.nativeElement.value = "";
      }
      else {
        this.fileSelected = true;
        this.invalidFileType = false;
        this.readFile();
      }
    }
  }

  readFile(): void {
    const fileReader = new FileReader();

    fileReader.onload = (e: any) => {
      const binaryString = e.target.result;
      console.log(binaryString);
      const workBook = XLSX.read(binaryString, { type: 'binary' });

      const workSheetName = workBook.SheetNames[0];
      const workSheet = workBook.Sheets[workSheetName];

      // Parse the Excel data into JSON format
      this.data = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(workSheet);
      console.log(this.data);
    }
  }
}
```

Below is my html code

```
<div class="search-form">
  <mat-card>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-1">
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-11">
        <h2 class="font--bold">system</h2>
        <form name="#systemform" #systemform="ngForm" role="search" (ngSubmit)="UploadFile(systemform.value)" novalidate>
          <!--Start-->
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <input #fileUpload type="file" class="file-upload" name="fileUpload" id="fileUpload" accept=".xlsx,.xls,.csv" required (change)="onFileChange($event)">
              <div class="invalidFileTypeAlert" *ngIf="invalidFileType">Invalid file type. Allowed: .xlsx, .xls, .csv</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <button (click)="UploadFile(systemform.value)" type="button" mat-raised-button color="primary" [disabled]="!fileSelected">Upload</button>
              <button (click)="Reset(systemform.value)" mat-raised-button [disabled]="!fileSelected">Reset</button>
              <h5>Please upload excel file </h5>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </mat-card>
</div>
```

Comment: `data` is only ever given a value if `readFile` is called. Have you verified that that function is actually being called, and that the `onload` listening is also running?

Comment: Thank you for response, yes I can see that readFile is called

Answer (score 0):

Please check if the call of XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json returns the value you expect. I tend to think the problem would be from there.

Comment: Thank you for the response, I found the issue

Comment: @BabaYaga Welcome to StackOverflow!  When you post an answer, please be sure you are confident in your answer.  Based on your language it seems as if you have made a guess, you might post that in discussions, but it's not appropriate for answer and could get you down voted.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

I found the answer , I missed to add below line in readFile method
fileReader.readAsBinaryString(this.file);